# Ionic refresher pullingIcon shows up even at the most bottom of the page when scrolling up

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, ionic3, refresher

I am using **Ionic 3** and I used the [ionic-refresher](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/) to reload and load some new data from an API provider when the page is refresh that is working fine.

However when I scroll down below and decided to scroll up back again. The refresher pulling icon always shop up even at the bottom or center part of the content which I don't want to happen.

I only want to shop up the `pullingIcon` at the most top part of the content when it reaches the `ion-navbar` or the `header component`.

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content
      pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
      pullingText="Pull to refresh"
      refreshingSpinner="circles"
      refreshingText="Refreshing...">
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>

</ion-content>
```

The code which I implemented is the same as the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/) example with just different method when refreshed.

Is this an issue?

I also have the code inside of my content which is at the bottom of the `ion-refresher` ending tag. This is the code below:

```
<ion-slides #mySlider (ionSlideDidChange)="onSlideChanged($event)">
```

Is it a conflict because of the **ion-slides** or just an issue?

The only css that I had modified is this below:

```
.refresher-pulling-icon, .refresher-refreshing-icon{
  color: red
}

.refresher-refreshing .spinner-crescent circle, .refresher-refreshing .spinner-ios line, .refresher-refreshing .spinner-ios-small line{
       stroke : red;
    }
```

But I don't think that this has involved or the cause of the issue.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try commenting or removing ion-slide code from that page and check if that's what is affecting ? Coz slides has the swipe touch event and as its inside ion-content can be the issue not sure though.

Comment: You can try this workarounds suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879731/using-ion-slides-with-ion-refresher-ionic